# Insert variable into formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to input a variable into a formula in my VBA code however there seems to be a object defined error which i can't seem to identify. Here is a sample of my code:

```
Sub test()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim newRow As Long
    
  ' Specify the worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Skill Matrix") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    
  ' Find the last used row in Column A
  lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    
  ' Determine the next available row
  newRow = IIf(lastRow = 1 And ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = "", 1, lastRow + 1)

  Dim Trainer As String

  Trainer = InputBox("Enter trainer for Row " & newTow & ":")

  With ws
    .Cells(newRow, 13).Formula = "=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, " & Trainer & ", IF($P" & newRow & ":$XFD" & newRow & "=5, IF($P$5:$XFD$5<>"",$P$5:$XFD$5, ""),"")), "")" ' Trainer formula in Column M

  End With
End Sub
```

The formula i keyed in works on excel however i am unsure why it doesn't seem to work in VBA

The Trainer input box was will prompt the user to key in an input. Afterwards the input will then be inserted into the formula as stated above and the formula will then be keyed into the cell

Comment: Your code as posted cannot run because of typos, and your formula string as posted does not create a valid formula. Please provide something that can be used to recreate your problem.  As posted, your macro returns `Compile Error: Syntax Error`

Comment: Try `.Cells(newRow, 13).Formula = "=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("", "", TRUE, " & Trainer & ", IF($P" & newRow & ":$XFD" & newRow & "=5, IF($P$5:$XFD$5<>"",$P$5:$XFD$5, ""),"")), "")"` . Double quotation markers are need for the first parameter of TEXTJOIN.

Comment: @taller you are correct that double quotes needs to be padded. Same goes for `IF($P$5:$XFD$5<>"",$P$5:$XFD$5, ""),"")), "")"` part of the formula as well :)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments to your question state, it seems the error is on the line where you populate the formula to the cell and it's because of double quotes in the code.
I found two ways you could solve this: one is padding, as the comments suggest, and the other is using chars instead of double quotes. Both examples are in the code below as Solution 1) and Solution 2) and the result is the following formula (hope this helps):
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("", "", TRUE, User_input_for_Trainer, IF($P1:$XFD1=5, IF($P$5:$XFD$5<>"",$P$5:$XFD$5, ""),"")), "")

```
Sub test()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim newRow As Long
  ' Specify the worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Skill Matrix") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
  ' Find the last used row in Column A
  lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  ' Determine the next available row
  newRow = IIf(lastRow = 1 And ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = "", 1, lastRow + 1)
  
  Dim Trainer As String
  Trainer = InputBox("Enter trainer for Row " & newTow & ":")
  'Solution 1) padding/surrounding double quotes with addition quotes """"
  ws.Cells(newRow, 13).Formula = "=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("""", """", TRUE, " & Trainer & ", IF($P" & newRow & ":$XFD" & newRow & "=5, IF($P$5:$XFD$5<>"""",$P$5:$XFD$5, """"),"""")), """")" ' Trainer formula in Column M
  'Solution 2) using char in place of double quotes: " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "
  ws.Cells(newRow, 14).Formula = "=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ", TRUE, " & Trainer & ", IF($P" & newRow & ":$XFD" & newRow & "=5, IF($P$5:$XFD$5<>" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",$P$5:$XFD$5, " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")), " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")" ' Trainer formula in Column M
End Sub
```